# Cauchy integral formula: can it be proved like this?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the Cauchy theorem:

Let $D\subset \mathbb C$ be a domain such that $\partial D$ is smooth and $\overline{D}$ is compact. Let $f$ be holomorphic on $D$ and continuous on the closure. Then $$\int_{\partial D}f(z) dz = 0$$.

> Is this a valid proof?

Use Stokes' theorem as follows:

$$ \int_{\partial D}f(z) dz = \int_D d(f(z) dz) = \int_D g(z) ddz = 0$$
since $ddz = 0$. Here $g(z)$ is some smooth map that is equal to $df(z)$.

Comment: Where did you use that $f$ was holomorphic?

Comment: @mollyerin In order for $f(x) dx$ to be a differential $1$-form, by definition the $f$ has to be smooth. A holomorphic map is smooth therefore this is a one form.

Comment: This theorem isn't true for smooth functions, so you're going to need more than just that $f$ is smooth. Note that $z$ is not a real variable, so you need to be careful when applying things like d to things like "z" -- "z" isn't a real-valued function, so what should dz mean? (These are pedagogical questions -- I'll also say that there is a way to get Cauchy's theorem from Stokes' theorem.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mollyerin says, you need to be more careful. I would use the following argument.

Let $u,v:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be the real and imaginary parts of $f$, and let $x,y,$ be real coordinates on $D$. We have $$f(z)dz=(u(z)+iv(z))(dx+idy)=u(z)dx-v(z)dy+i(u(z)dy+v(z)dx).$$Since $f$ is holomorphic, the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that both real and imaginary part of the above $1$-form are closed. By Stokes' theorem, the integral of a closed form on a boundary vanishes. The theorem follows.

Comment: But 
$$d(u(z)dx -  v(z) dy) = u_y dx \wedge dy -  v_x dy \wedge dx $$ How is this zero?

Comment: @astudent By Cauchy-Riemann we have $u_y+v_x=0$.

Comment: Wow I still manage to make sign errors. Thank you for your help! Btw, the argument is that because $d(f(z)dz)=0$ $f(z) dz$ is a closed $1$-form so that $$ \int_{\partial D} f(z) dz = \int_D d(f(z)dz) = 0$$RIght?

Comment: @astudent Yes, that's right.

Comment: If you are comfortable with complex differential forms, there is no need to do a detour over $dx$ and $dy$. You can check that $$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \,dz + \frac{\partial  f}{\partial \bar z}\,d\bar z$$ and since $f$ is assumed to be holomorphic, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0$.